# SharePoint online - Search metadata URLOWSURLH returning null / undefined

Tags: sharepoint-online, search-results

For SharePoint online environment, I need to search the content with links content type for my site.

As per my requirement, I have created separate display template for links content type. In side the display template, I want to hyperlink the link to title i.e. when i search of "Paycheck", I should be ale to see the entry with link to "https://xxxxxxx.adp...."

[image]

On search results page, I am able to get the display template code working but somehow unable to get the column url value. I am trying to use "URLOWSURLH" parameter but its giving null.

Also "URLOWSURLH" show correct value when used to query using rest api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems, MS have recently made changes to the managed metadata property. Check if the URLOWSURLH managed property has set correct mapped crawled property ows_q_URLH_URL.
[image]

This resolved my problem (fyi, wait for few minutes for crawl to complete.You can also re index site)